# String element counting doesn't work [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, count

I'm programming a simple server socket interface (like a console). I tryed to implement a `SEND TO xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` command to send some information or commands to the client at ip address `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. So I tryed writing this code (it is inside a class and this is the reason why appears the self parameter):

```
while True:
    # other statements

    # asking an input from the user
    command = input(f"[Server] >>> ")

    if command.startswith("SEND TO ") and \
        re.match(r"^([A-Z\s]){7}\s([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}([0-9]{1,3})$", command):

        # getting the ip address
        ip_address = command[8:]

        # ip lists (from self.__clients which is the list of connected 
        # clients)
        ip_list = [str(c.getpeername()[0]) for c in self.__clients]

        # count the occurrencies of the chosen ip (this because there can be 
        # multiple client connected from the same computer)
        matching_ip = ip_list.count(str(ip_address))

        # trying to print the results for debugging the code
        print(matching_ip)
        print(ip_list)
        print(ip_address)
```

And this is the console:

```
[Server] >>> SEND TO 111.111.1.11
0
['111.111.1.11', '111.111.1.11']
111.111.1.11
```

I can't figure out why even if there are 2 occurrencies of the same ip, the matching ip variable remains to the value 0. When I try to copy the ip from the previous output (using the mouse and `CTRL+C`) and paste (`CTRL-V`) to a new line, using the same `SEND TO` command it works, and it is returned:

```
# where 111.111.1.11 is copied from the previous output (this works even if
# I copy 111.111.1.11 from a previous program run and i paste it for the
# first time in the current run)

[Server] >>> SEND TO 111.111.1.11
2
['111.111.1.11', '111.111.1.11']
111.111.1.11
```

Any advices to fix this?

Thank you very much for your time and excuse my English, I'm still practising it

Comment: Any `\n` terminating your input? Then `ip_addess` will also contain that `\n`. Consider using a regex group to extract the ip address which you already matched.

Comment: Actually there is no `\n` in the input, which is a statement like `command = input("[Server] >>> ")`

Comment: I think in ip_address you are getting a white space. Try using ip_address.strip(). Or you can do **ip_address = command[8:].strip()**

Comment: I've tryied and it still doesn't work...

Comment: If you are working with windows, you may need to remove `\r` too